# File permissions across samba share

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, samba, cifs

I've been trying to figure out how to manage a file permissions issue that I'm having, but any combination of things that I've seen in researching the problem haven't resolved my issue.

I have two servers running under a hypervisor at home. One of which is a file server (#fs) and the other is a media server (#plex). I have a separate partition set up that is mounted on fs at /mnt/storage/. There is a sub directory that is a samba share at /mnt/storage/media. I have transmission-daemon running on #fs that downloads to that directory by default, and then I move them to the appropriate subdirectory of movies or tv. Transmission runs on #fs as user @debian-transmission and plexmediaserver runs on #plex as user @plex.

```
Servers: #plex and #fs
Users: @plex and @debian-transmission
Shares: $media
Groups: %media
```

The media share is mounted on plex via /etc/fstab at boot with the following line (please disregard the insecure practice of listing the password in /etc/fstab):

```
//10.0.0.96/media   /mnt/shares/media   cifs    username=plex,password=#REDACTED#   0   0
```

The media share is shared from fs with the following config in smb.conf

```
[media]
comment = Media files
path = /mnt/storage/media
read only = no
browsable = yes
create mask = 0777
```

On both #fs and #plex, I have tried creating a group called %media and making that group the owner of the directory recursively. On #fs, this seems to work, however, on #plex, it never changes the permission from root root.

Plex needs read write permissions in order to add media to its internal library. Debian-transmission also needs the same in order to be able to download torrents. In some combination of things that I've attempted I've done chmod 777 to $media and still not gotten the desired outcome. Below is the current state of affairs, I'm not sure how to maintain the file permissions when going across a samba share. I don't mind if this winds up with everyone having full access to these shares as this is all at home behind a firewall and is nothing overly important. And of course, I want these permissions to be inherited as when transmission downloads a new torrent, it changes the permissions on the new files/folders.

Members of %media on #plex:

```
javitab@plex:/$ grep media /etc/group
media:x:1005:plex
```

Members of %media on #fs:

```
javitab@fs:/$ grep media /etc/group
media:x:3081:javitab,plex,debian-transmission
```

Permissions of /mnt/storage/media on #fs:

```
javitab@fs:/$ sudo chown -R debian-transmission:media media
javitab@fs:/$ ls -la /mnt/storage/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  5 javitab             root   4096 Jun 24 01:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root                root   4096 Jun 23 15:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 javitab             root   4096 Jun 24 05:48 javitab
drwx------  2 javitab             root  16384 Jun 23 01:32 lost+found
drwxrwsrwx+ 4 debian-transmission media  4096 Jun 24 16:31 media
```

Permissions of /mnt/shares/media on #plex:

```
javitab@plex:/$ sudo chown -R plex:media /mnt/shares/media
javitab@plex:/$ ls -la /mnt/shares/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 23 23:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 23 23:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun 24 16:31 media
```

Comment: I use this on my mounts on my own server. //192.168.5.39/data /share/data cifs sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials 0 0, but I'm connecting to a windows share.

Comment: @GeekyDaddy I had some similar arguments when I started out and it gave me some troubles so I went real simple, but will try some of the file and dir mode arguments when I get home.